# JavaScript checking for a specific hash

Tags: javascript, hash

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (location.href.indexOf("#") != -1) {
    // Your code in here accessing the string like this
    // location.href.substr(location.href.indexOf("#"))
    alert('hello');
}
</script>
```

I found this script in another answer. Is there a way for me to use the

```
("#") != myParameter)
```

So if the hash meets my parameter do something.

Thank you.

Comment: The unsolved problem here is how to deal with URLencoding; e.g. `if (location.hash == '#'+id)` isn't quite right if e.g. `id == "HQ9+"`, because you'll find that `location.hash == "#HQ9%2B"` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
if(location.hash.substr(1) == myParameter)
  //Do something
```

This takes the hash, chops off the "#", and compares it to `myParameter`.
You could also compare directly to a string:

```
if(location.hash.substr(1) == "string_here")
  //Do something
```

If you want the "#" when comparing, use `location.hash` instead of `location.hash.substr(1)`.

Comment: So I would put myParameter into a variable then? var myParameter = ref=22

Comment: @RPM Yes, but it should be a string: `var myParameter = "ref=22"` You could also compare directly: `if(location.hash.substr(1) == "ref=22")//Do something`

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear, but if you're asking how you can check for a hash, and derive its value, this snippet will work:

```
  var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1)
  // Now do something with your hash variable, 
  // e.g. compare it to another value:
  if(hash=="some value"){
    // Do stuff
  }
```

Comment: I'm trying to check the url for a defined hash (its not dynamic).

Comment: OK, well given the `hash` variable in my answer, `if(hash=="your value")` is the test you need.